# Formulário de contato HTML + PHP

Tags: php, html, formulário

Olá! Estou fazendo um site onde o cliente pediu um formulário de contato, mas entendo muito pouco de php. Então procurei na internet tutoriais de como utilizar essa função.
Está enviando o e-mail normalmente, mas só aparece a mensagem de enviado, e não tem nenhuma mensagem de erro, caso algum campo não esteja correto.
Qual a melhor forma de fazer isto? Vi em outros tópicos, o pessoal falando do PHPMailer, é mais prático?

Aqui está o resultado do meu código PHP:

```
<?php

// Recebendo os dados
$recebenome     = $_POST["nome"];
$recebefone     = $_POST["fone"];
$recebemail     = $_POST["email"];
$recebeassunto  = $_POST["assunto"];
$recebemsg      = $_POST["msg"];

// Definindo os cabeçalhos do e-mail
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8 \n"; 
$headers .= "From: Formulario de contato\n"; 

// Destinatário do email
$para = "contato@jefsilva.com.br";

// Definindo o aspecto da mensagem
$mensagem   = "<h3>De:</h3> ";
$mensagem  .= $recebenome;
$mensagem  .= "<h3>Contato:</h3>";
$mensagem  .= $recebefone.' - E-mail: '.$recebemail;
$mensagem  .= "<h3>Observações</h3>";
$mensagem  .= "<p>";
$mensagem  .= $recebemsg;
$mensagem  .= "</p>";

// Enviando a mensagem para o destinatário
mail($para,'Contato pelo site - de: '.$recebenome,$mensagem,$headers);

// Resposta Automática, preparando o e-mail com a resposta.
$mensagem2  = "<p>Olá <strong>" . $recebenome . "</strong>.<p>Agradecemos sua visita ao nosso site e a oportunidade de receber-mos seu contato.
<br />Em breve responderemos sua questão através de correio eletrônico.</p><br><p>OBS.: Não é necessário responder esta mensagem!</p><br>";
$mensagem2 .= "<p>Atenciosamente<br />Firenze ".$empresa."</p>";

// Enviando a resposta sutomática

$envia =  mail($recebemail,"Agradecemos sua visita ao nosso site",$mensagem2,$headers);

// Exibe um alert que a mensagem foi enviada com sucesso.
echo '<script>
                alert("Mesagem enviada com sucesso!");history.go(-1);
          </script>';

?>
```

E aqui o código HTML:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="mail.php">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fone" name="fone" placeholder="Telefone" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="assunto" name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Mensagem" maxlength="180" rows="6"></textarea>
<span class="help-block"><p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">You have reached the limit</p></span>                    
</div>

<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-send pull-right">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Usa o phpMailer, o campo `from` do email deve ser um email e não formulario de contato.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a autenticação HTML javascript nos campos assim a pessoa é alertada enquanto digita.

Não é interessante você utilizar a função mail do php pois as mensagens podem ir para o lixo ou ser rejeitadas pelo servidor. É melhor utilizar sempre o php mailer.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada como funciona o php mailer! E a autenticação que tu diz é validação por js?

Comment: @JefSilva, sim, ele se refere a validação por JS. Ainda recomendo refazer a validação no servidor (PHP). O phpMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) é uma library (biblioteca) que você inclui (normalmente) no topo do arquivo php que vai enviar as mensagens. É realmente muito superior à função mail() do php que não deve ser usada.

Comment: @ReneFreak não deve ser usada porque? Não vejo nenhum problema nela se você não precisa dos extras que a PHPMailer oferece. Sobre o resto, concordo.

Comment: @Bacco, por causa da forma como é implementada. Só deve ser usada em casos muito simples e mesmo assim, costuma causar problemas, como enviar mensagens pro lixo eletrônico (pela forma como opera). Se não gosta do `phpMailer`, pode usar `swiftmailer`. E se estiver usando `mail()` sem problemas, ignore!

Comment: @ReneFreak perguntei pra ver se vc teria alguma referência como obsolecência, mas pelo comentário, acho que vc está confundindo um pouco as coisas. Não cai no lixo eletrônico se você fizer o SPF corretamente no DNS, e dá para mandar com qualquer complexidade que quiser, com anexos, HTML, só não costuma compensar o trabalho. O fato é que como você comentou, deu a impressão que o mail() tinha algum problema real, sendo que no caso, o único problema dele é mau uso pelo "programador" (tanto que se fosse obsoleto, constaria da documentação).

Comment: Quanto à implementação, tem realmente um ponto: no windows tem umas diferenças, mas documentadas. Vale notar que o tipo de "oposição" ao `mail()` que se encontra de fontes seguras é o mesmo que o mencionado no próprio PHP Mailer: _the **vast majority of code that you'll find online** that uses the mail() function directly is just plain wrong_ - e isto é verdade: muito comum o pessoal usar sem saber (aliás, esse é um ponto comum em tudo que envolve PHP, a maior parte do que se acha online é realmente abaixo da média, mas tem coisas bem feitas).

Comment: @ReneFreak De qq forma, só quis levantar o assunto para esclarecer melhor o ponto de "não dever usar" (e de certa forma, realmente só deve ser usado se a pessoa tiver domínio sobre o assunto, por isto concordo que se a pessoa tem qq dúvida, melhor partir para o PHP Mailer diretamente). Grato pelo feedback. Só uma dica extra: Se a pessoa não quiser usar o PHP Mailer completo, e precisar de customização, pode tomar por base a parte de SMTP dele separadamente, que é excelente, como ponto de partida. (class.smtp.php). Neste arquivo tem tudo que é necessário para fazer o envio propriamente dito.

Comment: @Bacco, agradeço por responder a si mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

```
$to = "to@to.com";
$from = "from@from.com";
$subject = "subject";
$message = "mensagem";

$headers = "From: $from"; 
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f " . $from);
```

Comment: VagnerAraujo adicione algum conteúdo explicativo em sua resposta para que ela possa ser útil para outros membros além do autor da pergunta. OK?

Comment: Possa ser útil para o autor da pergunta também :D
Como eu disse, sei pouco sobre php...

Comment: Otimo , sem problemas =)